# PHP - how to implement IF in this case?

Tags: php

I have no idea about `PHP` coding.
I manage to put together a code that will pull some data from `MySQL`.
I can see the results as HTML table.

What I can't figure out:
I would like to add an `if` statement like, `if $x1 = ""` then do not echo anything, else return the results in the html table.

Here is what i have:

```
<?php 
$x1 = get_field(test);

$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxx";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

// select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("xxxx",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select examples");

// execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE xxxx = '$x1'");

// fetch tha data from the database
echo "<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Nick Name</th><th>Email</th></tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo 
"<tr><td>".$row["name_l"]."</td><td>".$row["nick_name"]."</td><td>".$row["email_s"]."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

//close the connection
mysql_close($dbhandle);
```

The problem with the code above is that when `$x1 = ""`, will echo the headers :/

Comment: You can work with a database but can't figure out how to write a basic if statement? Really?

Comment: @JohnConde, because SQL is a query language, I think more people are exposed to it than you might expect. Business analysts, administrative assistants, etc. Many offices are ruled by the all mighty-spreadsheet, and for expert users the jump to SQL isn't that jarring.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is how i fixed it.

```
//fetch tha data from the database
if ($x1 == '') {
echo "<table>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Nick Name</th><th>Email</th></tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo 
"<tr><td>".$row["name_l"]."</td><td>".$row["nick_name"]."</td><td>".$row["email_s"]."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";} else {}

//close the connection
mysql_close($dbhandle);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$x1 = get_field(test);

if($x1!=""){
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxx";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("xxxx",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select examples");

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE xxxx = '$x1'");

//fetch tha data from the database

echo "<table>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Nick Name</th><th>Email</th></tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo 
"<tr><td>".$row["name_l"]."</td><td>".$row["nick_name"]."</td><td>".$row["email_s"]."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

//close the connection
mysql_close($dbhandle);}
?>
```

Comment: i can still see the table Headers :/

Comment: is this the condition? if ($x1!=""

Comment: Well even if the $x1 has no value, the html table is creating and i can see the headers.

Comment: what comes up when you do `$x1 = get_field(test);` then `echo "test $x1";`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this :

```
<?php 
$x1 = get_field("test");
if($x1){

$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxx";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("xxxx",$dbhandle) 
or die("Could not select examples");

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE xxxx = '$x1'");

//fetch tha data from the database

echo "<table>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Nick Name</th><th>Email</th></tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo 
"<tr><td>".$row["name_l"]."</td><td>".$row["nick_name"]."   </td><td>".$row["email_s"]."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

//close the connection
mysql_close($dbhandle);
} 
else {echo "Sorry, Nothing to display"; }

?>
```